# Is there a way to copy/move many frames at the same time?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

In lowriter I've a form that has been designed using many floating frames for a page size of A6/landscape (it's a receipt). Is it possible to modify the document so I can have two copies of it centered in an A4/portrait on top and bottom half?

I found no way to select multiple frames and the only solution I can see now is to select, copy, paste and reposition each single frame manually... and that's probably more work than just redesigning the whole thing from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to work with multiple text frames at the same time.

LibreOffice Draw however has no problem working with multiple objects and it's a better tool if you need to design complex forms.